# How do I name a chart object?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I change the name of a chartobject instead of referring it as ChartObject(1)? The Chartobject is on a sheet named "Unit2SelectedData"

```
Sheets("Unit2SelectedData").ChartObjects.Add Left:=1700, Top:=50, Width:=800, Height:=400
Sheets("Unit2SelectedData").ChartObjects(1).Activate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `ChartObject` first, and then name it:

```
Dim ChtObj As ChartObject

Set ChtObj = Sheets("Unit2SelectedData").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=1700, Top:=50, Width:=800, Height:=400)
ChtObj.Name = "My Chart"
```